# Trying to give a two different tints to background image using slanted divs

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I am a new to learning HTML and CSS and I am trying to give a background image two tilted tint with slanted divs. I can't understand how to do it so that the slant is only in the middle and not on the edges of the image. Here's what I have tried so far.

```css
.tinted-image {
  
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/175941/pexels-photo-175941.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.85), rgba(0,0,0, 0.85));
  tranform-origin: bottom-left;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
/*   margin-left: 1em; */
}
#two{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .45), rgba(255, 255, 255, .45));
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
#one, #two{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family:'Nova Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

#one h1 {
  color: #eee;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#two h1 {
  color: #222;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="tinted-image">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<div id = "one"><h1>WEB</h1></div>
<div id = "two"><h1>DEV</h1></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the desired effect by using a [negative margin](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) on the left `margin-left: -200px;` and a positive left padding with the same amount  `padding-left: 200px;` to offset it.

I added those two to your selector `#one` alongside `overflow: hidden;` to [tidy things up](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

**Working example:**

```css
.tinted-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/175941/pexels-photo-175941.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85));
  tranform-origin: bottom-left;
  margin-left: -200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
  /*   margin-left: 1em; */
}

#two {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .45), rgba(255, 255, 255, .45));
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}

#one,
#two {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Nova Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

#one h1 {
  color: #eee;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#two h1 {
  color: #222;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="tinted-image">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <div id="one">
    <h1>WEB</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <h1>DEV</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```